# Firebase commitChangesWithCompletion on ProfileChangeRequest Not Firing

Tags: ios, firebase

I take the exact code from the Firebase Reference, put it inside of a method, and the completion handler (nor the function) execute.  Does anyone have any idea why?

```
let user = FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser
if let user = user {
    let changeRequest = user.profileChangeRequest()

    changeRequest.displayName = "Jane Q. User"
    changeRequest.photoURL =
    NSURL(string: "https://example.com/jane-q-user/profile.jpg")
      changeRequest.commitChangesWithCompletion { error in
    if let error = error {
      // An error happened.
    } else {
      // Profile updated.
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might not have worked because you tried printing the username or displaying it before the completion block finished. You can dispatch to the main thread inside the completion block to segue when appropriate. That is what happened to me, so just my guess.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to give more context. When are you calling this function? What type of function is this block of code placed in?

The location of this function is very important. Make sure that wherever you have this block of code, that the program is actually stepping into that section of code.

Sometimes people realize that the Documentation functions don't work because they were never called in the first place. I recommend to read through [Firebase's Documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/manage-users#get_a_users_provider-specific_profile_information) a few more times, make sure that you understand how to use these functions.

Comment: Thanks for you comment.  Not sure if this was an xcode anomaly or a race condition, but it just started working.  You are correct though function placement is very important to make sure the proper closure is executed at the appropriate time.