# How to update user with displayName

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-authentication

So I use `FIRAuth`'s `createUserWithEmail` to create new user.  I also want to assign the `displayName` for this user.  But this function only accept email and password.  What do I go about to insert `displayName`?

```
FIRAuth.auth()?.createUserWithEmail(email, password: password, completion: { (user: FIRUser?, error: NSError?) in


})
```

Edit: So there seemed to be a function called updateProfile.  But it does not seem to be available for the iOS platform library.  Any idea?

Edit: Found solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37693440/firebase-commitchangeswithcompletion-on-profilechangerequest-not-firing): Need to use `profileChangeRequest` function

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When you want to change the details of a user in Firebase, you want to use `FIRAuth.auth().currentUser.profileChangeRequest`in order to update any details other than the user's email and password. To update their email or password, you need to use a specific method for each. `updateEmail` and `updatepassword`

Answer (score 17):

Documentation is [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/manage-users#update_a_users_profile)

```
let changeRequest = Auth.auth().currentUser?.createProfileChangeRequest()
changeRequest?.displayName = displayName
changeRequest?.commitChanges { (error) in
  // ...
}
```